# Prompt User to Open a Workbook and to Select a Worksheet, opens an blank file

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I would like the User to choose a Workbook and then select the worksheet that they need. The code works perfectly when it is Debug - Step Into. But, When the complete macro is run through the button, the file do get open  and prompts to choose the sheet but no sheets or cells are visible. It's all BLANK. There is no protection to the file. Column names and Row numbers are not visible

```
 Sub LoadData()
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim desiredSheetName As String
     Dim c As String

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     ans = MsgBox("Choose the file to retrive the data?", vbYesNo, "Choose Source")
     If ans = vbYes Then
        myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")
        If myfile <> False Then
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Destination").Range("AA2") = myfile
           Set src_data = Workbooks.Open(myfile)

          On Error Resume Next
          desiredSheetName = InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ",type:=8).worksheet.name 
          sht = desiredSheetName
          On Error GoTo 0

          Set dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

          src_data.Activate

          lastcell = src_data.Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
          LastRowD = dest.Cells(dest.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row

          src_data.Activate
          Sheets(sht).Select
          Range("A:B,D:D").Select
          Selection.Copy
          dest.Activate
          Range("F1").Select
          Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

          src_data.Close False

          dest.Select

        End If
   Else
     Exit Sub
 End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to not turn screen updating off until after you ask for the range selection, because when the macro is running, the file will open but the screen doesn't update to show the cells.

A few other pointers given your code:

- You're using variables you haven't declared (`sht`, `srcData`).
- If you're using a variable only once (like `ans` from your MessageBox), just plug that in directly instead of dimming a variable and using that. The exception would be when using a constant like a number. Always better in that case to use a meaningful variable name than a hardcoded number without context.
- You should set `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and you'll be
  warned about this using undeclared variables.
- You're getting `destinationSheet` and then setting
  `sht` to the same thing. Why not just get rid of `sht` altogether?
- Rather than mixing variable naming conventions (`src_data` and `desiredSheetName`), just pick one and stick with it (I use the latter format myself).
- Selecting and activating things is usually the wrong way to do it
  unless you're doing it so the user can see something specific.
  Usually you should just do the operations on the ranges and sheets
  themselves. Also, you should be explicit about the worksheet you're using (because otherwise it defaults to ActiveSheet). For example:

Rather than:

```
Range("A:B,D:D").Select
Selection.Copy
dest.Activate
Range("F1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Do:

```
src_data.Range("A:B,D:D").Copy
dest.Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

That makes it very clear where you're copying from and where you're pasting to, is fewer lines of code, and is also faster to process.

So here's the final code, with clearly named, defined variables, no `Select`ing of sheets, non-used variables cut out.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoadData()
     Dim sourcePath As String
     Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
     Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
     Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
     Dim lastSourceRow As Long
     Dim lastDestinationRow As Long

     'Application.ScreenUpdating = False '==>Moved after InputBox
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     Set destinationWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

     If MsgBox("Choose the file to retrive the data?", vbYesNo, "Choose Source") = vbYes Then
        sourcePath = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for Workbook")
        If sourcePath <> "False" Then
          destinationWorksheet.Range("A2") = sourcePath
          Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourcePath)

          On Error Resume Next
          sourceWorksheet = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select any cell inside the target sheet:", Type:=8).Worksheet
          On Error GoTo 0

          Application.ScreenUpdating = False

          lastSourceRow = sourceWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
          lastDestinationRow = destinationWorksheet.Cells(destinationWorksheet.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(0).Row

          sourceWorksheet.Range("A:B,D:D").Copy
          destinationWorksheet.Range("F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, skipblanks:=False, Transpose:=False

          sourceWorkbook.Close False

          destinationWorksheet.Select

        End If
   Else
     Exit Sub
 End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and insights into my code. I tried your code, and I am facing few errors - 1) sourceWorksheet, is assigned to "Nothing" when I hoover. 2) lastSourceRow gives an Runtime eroor 91, which states, Object variable or with block variable not set.

Answer (score 0):

When `myfile = False` you end up exiting the sub with screen updating turned off. You either need to

1. Ensure your code always runs from start to end OR
2. Turn applications back on before doing an early exit.

---

```
If myfile <> False Then
    'Your code here
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  '<--- Re-enable before early exit
    Exit Sub
End If
```

---

If you need to correct this for the instance of excel you currently have open just run the single line to re-enable screen updating

```
Sub Oof ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
```